# TestNG + Spring + Maven = Cannot load context

Tags: spring, maven, testng

I am using Maven with surefire plugin to run TestNG test by extending AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests and it appears the context is not loaded even if it is in classpath, and the test works correctly inside my ide, but not in maven.

@ContextConfiguration(locations =
Array("classpath*:/com/gottex/gottware/server/offlinepuwithdummydatafeed.xml"))
 My xml is under src/test/com/gottex/gottware/server

My parent pom contains:

```
            <build>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>

                </configuration>

            </plugin> ...
```

and my children pom does not contain anything if not dependencies..

Comment: Which Maven version? How does you pom look like?

Answer (score 0):

After a long debugging session, I was finally able to find the problem. It lies at ClassLoader level, and it exhibits itself when debugging

**org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver**
 inside the method *findAllClassPathResources*

```
protected Resource[] findAllClassPathResources(String location) throws IOException {
        String path = location;
        if (path.startsWith("/")) {
            path = path.substring(1);
        }
        Enumeration resourceUrls = getClassLoader().getResources(path);
        Set<Resource> result = new LinkedHashSet<Resource>(16);
        while (resourceUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL url = (URL) resourceUrls.nextElement();
            result.add(convertClassLoaderURL(url));
        }
        return result.toArray(new Resource[result.size()]);
    }
```

This is done when the context is loaded, and produce the following result:

- When you run inside idea, the ClassLoader is java.net.URLClassLoader and this works correctly
- When runnigng tests throuh Maven-Surefire plugin, a different classloader is used: ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9,
  parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@61ba34f2]

The second classLoader returns a enumeration resourceUrls with no "moreElements" and therefore the context is not loaded, but no failure is thrown by the framework.